# Flask variables to html

Tags: python, flask

I am new to flask. I have a python script that scrapes a couple of websites for data. It's running fine but I want to present the result in an easy html page so I started to look at Flask. In my script, I basically have this piece of code

```
#main.py
for shop in shops:
    print shop 
    service = get_services(shop)
    for s in service:
        print s

#scraper.py
shops = {
    'Shop Alpha':'https://www.shopalpha.com',
    'Shop Bravo': 'https://www.shopbravo.com',
    'Shop Charlie': 'https://www.shopcharlie.com'
    }

def get_services(shop):

    r = requests.get(shops[shop])
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "html.parser")
    service = service_scraper(shop, soup)
    # here I call my scraping methods
    return service
```

Which produces this output when I run the script:

```
Shop Alpha
Cars
Bikes

Shop Bravo
Boats

Shop Charlie
Helicopters
Planes
Tanks
```

I tried to add this piece of code

```
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/", methods=["GET"])
def index():
    return render_template('index.html',**locals())
app.run(debug=True)
```

What is the easiest way of passing variables to the html page? What I would like, is to use the for loop but in the html. Is that possible? What do I need to pass then?

For example, can I pass variables so I will be able to use something like this in the html:

```
<body>
  {% for shop in shops %}
  <h4>{{ shop }}</h4>
  {% endfor %}
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how to do it

```
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/", methods=["GET"])
def index():
    # Get shops
    shops = get_shops()
    return render_template('index.html', shops = shops)
app.run(debug=True)
```

Try to save **scraped** data in a database or a file to not crawl the urls every time you load `index` and then read it inside `index` endpoint then loop through data in `index.html`

```
<body>
  {% for shop in shops %}
  <h4>{{ shop }}</h4>
  {% endfor %}
</body>
```

Comment: I'd consider pointing @wazza to the documentation as well, as this sort of question is well covered in easily found tutorials: https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-ii-templates

Comment: But the problem I have is in the python code, I iterate over shops in the for loop and for each shop I call get_service and pass the current shop. That I can not do in the html I assume.

Comment: @wazza It is not recommanded to crawl links while rendering your page. What you instead need to do is crawling shops' links and save the results in a file (or a database) and read shops from that file (or database). To keep your data fresh have a `cron` job to fetch data once in a while.